# rename columnName and change column's data type in a table by using ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, ado.net

how can I by using Ado.net rename existing column in a table and changing a column's data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call stored procedure for that, as follows

```
EXEC sp_rename 'MyTable.OldColumnName', 'NewColumnName'
```

see section: `Renaming a Column` in [**this Article**](http://www.functionx.com/vbasic/adonet/Lesson04.htm)

Comment: and you also agree with me for changing column data Type use something like this? ALTER TABLE tableName ALTER COLUMN colName nvarchar(50).
for example: a have column with nvarchar(50) data type? and it's filled with values, how to me convert this column data type to int? firstly i must remove all data from this column?

Comment: Try this: ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN OldColumnName  nvarchar(50) NOT NULL